# How can I make an image header that takes the whole view without scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I want to make an image to use it for a simple slider that takes the whole first part of the browser without scrolling .

Here is my simple code:
HTML:

```
<div class="img-header">
    <img src="img/head.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I hope my question was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it, avoiding the image to stretch strangely, but to always have it 100% the **Viewport** is to use your image as a `background-image` set to `cover`

```css
html, body{margin:0; height:100%;}

.img-header{
  height:100vh;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkgPx.jpg) 50% / cover
}
```

```html
<div class="img-header"></div>
```

***[jsBin playground](http://jsbin.com/nefowi/2/edit?html,css,output)***

Comment: Yes now it's better, thank you !

Comment: @AmirNassal you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need to also define the `height` for `body, html` and the parent div. Like the following:

```css
.img-header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-header {
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-header">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300" />
</div>
```